# Report specific patches around a given turtle

Tags: netlogo

How can I use the function neighbors to report at once all patches that are located around each turtle according to this image?

[image]
Just note that in the example as detailed below, row and column start from upper-left corner of the world. Thus, (1,1) is the upper-left patch index.

By supposing that a turtle A (red cross in the image) is located at the patch x0 y0, the neighboring patches around this turtle will be:

%%% Direction 1: patches at the upper-left corner
`show patch (x0 – 2):(x0 – 1) (y0 – 2):(y0 – 1)` which returns the patches with coordinates (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)

%%% Direction 2: patches at the upper-middle corner
`show patch (x0 – 2):(x0 – 1) (y0 – 1):(y0 +1)` which returns the patches with coordinates (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4)

%%% Direction 3: patches at the upper-right corner
`show patch (x0 – 2):(x0 – 1) (y0 + 1):(y0 + 2)` which returns the patches with coordinates (1,4), (1,5), (2,4), (2,5)

%%% Direction 4: patches at the left corner
`show patch (x0 – 1):(x0 + 1) (y0 – 2):(y0 – 1)` which returns the patches with coordinates (2,1), (2,2), (3,1), (3,2), (4,1), (4,2)

%%% Direction 5: patches at the right corner
`show patch (x0 – 1):(x0 + 1) (y0 + 1):(y0 + 2)` which returns the patches with coordinates (2,4), (2,5), (3,4), (3,5), (4,4), (4,5)

%%% Direction 6: patches at the bottom-left corner
`show patch (x0 + 1):(x0 + 2) (y0 - 2):(y0 - 1)` which returns the patches with coordinates (4,1), (4,2), (5,1), (5,2)

%%% Direction 7: patches at the bottom-middle corner
`show patch (x0 + 1):(x0 + 2) (y0 - 1):(y0 + 1)` which returns the patches with coordinates (4,2), (4,3), (4,4), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4)

%%% Direction 8: patches at the bottom-right corner
`show patch (x0 + 1):(x0 + 2) (y0 + 1):(y0 + 2)` which returns the patches with coordinates (4,4), (4,5), (5,4), (5,5)

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I don't think neighbors is the way you'd want to go for this since neighbors refers to those patches that are touching your patch. Can you please better explain why the code examples you've provided are insufficient. I think what you want is to drop your code lines in a function and have the turtle run that. But again, I'm a bit confused on your final goal so I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build something around the use of [`patch-at`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-at):

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1 [ setxy 3 3 ]
  ask turtles [
    show patches-at [[-2 0] [-1 0] [0 -2] [0 -1]]
  ]
end

to-report patches-at [ list-of-xy-pairs ]
  report patch-set map get-patch-at list-of-xy-pairs
end

to-report get-patch-at [ xy-pair ]
  report patch-at first xy-pair last xy-pair
end
```